# Rotating "tikz/path picture" along curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

I want to draw curves and mark out some specific points with a cross. For this, lacking better options (and feel free to suggest any), I am using the `hobby` TikZ library, as in the following code (I found that marking out points on manually drawn Bézier curves was unnecessarily complicated). This yields the output from the first picture.

However, I would like the cross to be rotated along with the curve, as in the second picture.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\tikzset{
   cross/.style={
        path picture={
            \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\ensuremath{\times}};
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[use Hobby shortcut] (0,0) .. ++(.5,1)  .. node [cross] {} ++(1,.5) .. (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want (approximately):

[image]

Comment: A path picture is in the canvas (paper) cs, I'd suggest either `node[sloped, cross]{}` where `cross/.style={append after command={(\tikzlastnode.north west) edge (\tikzlastnode.south east) (\tikzlastnode.north east) edge (\tikzlastnode.south west)}}` or a pic, say `pic[sloped]{cross}` where `cross/.pic={\draw (-3mm,3mm) -- (3mm,-3mm) (-3mm,-3mm) -- (3mm, 3mm);}`. Why aren't you using `\times` directly as the node text?

Comment: You could also add `transform shape` to the node inside the `path picture` whhich would inherit the `sloped` from the outer node.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm not using `\times` directly in the node text because I want to be able to centrally control the notation with a clean and minimal syntax. Maybe later I might want to replace the cross syntax with e.g. a circle. Thanks for the suggestion, will try that when I get home.

Comment: That's a case for `cross/.style={node contents=\ensuremath{\times}}` and then using `.. node[cross] ..` (without `{}`!). If you later realize you need a `pic` and node a node, this can be setup in the style of `cross`, too. (A pic is just a node with a special flag set.)

Answer (score 2):

There is the `sloped` option. But it seems to work only on the node text itself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[use Hobby shortcut] (0,0) .. ++(.5,1)  .. node [sloped] {\ensuremath{\times}} ++(1,.5) .. (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution! Alternatively, one can (inspired by what @Qrrbrbirlbel said) do `cross/.style={sloped,node contents=\ensuremath{\times}}`. That seems to solve he problem completely.